# in Nifi and with QueryRecord processor can we add a new column that is a regex of another column

Tags: json, apache-nifi, processor, apache-calcite

in Nifi and with QueryRecord processor can we add a new column that is a regex of another column in a query?

Like : `SELECT info, SUBSTRING(info, "([^\s]+)") as f_name FROM FLOWFILE`

I don't want to split my flowfile, ExtractText, UpdateAttributes, then attributesToJson and MergeContent. seems like along loop and it will take time if we talking about 400MB per FlowFile with 100k+ rows each

input:

```
{"info":"Rachel: %Robert-100-400-4444-Mrs"}
{"info":": %Martin-200-500-5555-Mr"}
{"info":"%Holand-300-600-6666-Mr"}
```

desired output:

```
{"info":"Rachel: %Robert-100-400-4444-Mrs", "f_name":"Rachel","l_name":"Robert","area_code":100,"last_four_digit":4444,"title":"Mrs"}
{"info":": %Martin-200-500-5555-Mr", "f_name":"","l_name":"Martin","area_code":200,"last_four_digit":5555,"title":"Mr"}
{"info":"%Holand-300-600-6666-Mr", "f_name":"","l_name":"Holand","area_code":300,"last_four_digit":6666,"title":"Mr"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryRecord` will allow you to filter the records in the flowfile using a regex via `LIKE` ([one of the examples](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/additionalDetails.html) on the Additional Details page of the docs), but to *update* the record, you'll need to use `UpdateRecord`.

`UpdateRecord` uses the [RecordPath](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html) DSL syntax, which also has regex functions like [`replaceRegex`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#replaceregex) and [`matchesRegex`](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#matchesregex).